# INSERT multiple records using ruby on rails active record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, insert

Is there a way to INSERT multiple records rather than one at a time?

I have a very very ugly rake task that is doing the following ...

```
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR", :election => "2000-03-07", :party => row[45], :participate => participated(row[45]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "GE", :election => "2000-11-07", :party => row[46], :participate => participated(row[46])) 
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "SP", :election => "2000-05-08", :party => row[47], :participate => participated(row[47]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "GE", :election => "2001-11-06", :party => row[48], :participate => participated(row[48]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR", :election => "2002-05-07", :party => row[49], :participate => participated(row[49]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "GE", :election => "2002-11-05", :party => row[50], :participate => participated(row[50]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "SP", :election => "2003-05-06", :party => row[51], :participate => participated(row[51]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "GE", :election => "2003-11-04", :party => row[52], :participate => participated(row[52]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR", :election => "2004-03-02", :party => row[53], :participate => participated(row[53]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "GE", :election => "2004-11-02", :party => row[54], :participate => participated(row[54]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "SP", :election => "2005-02-08", :party => row[55], :participate => participated(row[55]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR", :election => "2005-05-03", :party => row[56], :participate => participated(row[56]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR", :election => "2005-09-13", :party => row[57], :participate => participated(row[56]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "GE", :election => "2005-11-08", :party => row[58], :participate => participated(row[58]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "SP", :election => "2006-02-07", :party => row[59], :participate => participated(row[59]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR", :election => "2006-05-02", :party => row[60], :participate => participated(row[60]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "GE", :election => "2006-11-07", :party => row[61], :participate => participated(row[61]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR", :election => "2007-05-08", :party => row[62], :participate => participated(row[62]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR", :election => "2007-09-11", :party => row[63], :participate => participated(row[63]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "GE", :election => "2007-11-06", :party => row[64], :participate => participated(row[64]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR", :election => "2007-11-06", :party => row[65], :participate => participated(row[65]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR", :election => "2007-12-11", :party => row[66], :participate => participated(row[66]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR", :election => "2008-03-04", :party => row[67], :participate => participated(row[67]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR", :election => "2008-10-14", :party => row[68], :participate => participated(row[68]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "GE", :election => "2008-11-04", :party => row[69], :participate => participated(row[69]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "GE", :election => "2008-11-18", :party => row[70], :participate => participated(row[70]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR", :election => "2009-05-05", :party => row[71], :participate => participated(row[71]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR", :election => "2009-09-08", :party => row[72], :participate => participated(row[72]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR", :election => "2009-09-15", :party => row[73], :participate => participated(row[73]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR", :election => "2009-09-29", :party => row[74], :participate => participated(row[74]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "GE", :election => "2009-11-03", :party => row[75], :participate => participated(row[75]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR", :election => "2010-05-04", :party => row[76], :participate => participated(row[76]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR", :election => "2010-07-13", :party => row[77], :participate => participated(row[77]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR", :election => "2010-09-07", :party => row[78], :participate => participated(row[78]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "GE", :election => "2010-11-02", :party => row[79], :participate => participated(row[79]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR", :election => "2011-05-03", :party => row[80], :participate => participated(row[80]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR", :election => "2011-09-13", :party => row[81], :participate => participated(row[81]))
        VoteRecord.create(:prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "GE", :election => "2011-11-08", :party => row[82], :participate => participated(row[82]))
```

This has to be extremely inefficient and there must be a better way...

Comment: "This has to be extremely inefficient" - what makes you think so?

Comment: its ugly. haha. If there is a better way I could benchmark the two and get back with you?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The `create` method takes also an array as parameter.

```
VoteRecord.create(
  [
    { :prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "GE", :election => "2011-11-08", :party => row[82], :participate => participated(row[82]) },
    { :prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR", :election => "2011-09-13", :party => row[81], :participate => participated(row[81]) }
    ...
  ]
)
```

However, this still executes one SQL query per entry instead of a single SQL query. It is more efficent, because it only has to create a single activerecord object under the hood.

> If you are inserting many rows from the same client at the same time,
>   use INSERT statements with multiple VALUES lists to insert several
>   rows at a time. This is considerably faster (many times faster in some
>   cases) than using separate single-row INSERT statements. If you are
>   adding data to a nonempty table, you can tune the
>   bulk_insert_buffer_size variable to make data insertion even faster.
>   See Section 5.1.3, “Server System Variables”.

[From the mysql page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html) (but I guess it should be the same for other dbs)

Comment: this does not do a single SQL statement, it does one per new object. i'm trying this on rails 3.2 -- maybe it was different in previous versions?

Comment: @JohnBachir Not sure about the various versions, but if you want to ensure that it's done at once (for performance), you can use a transaction. Though maybe rails is already doing that?..

Comment: @Nolan a transaction will not make it done in one statement. that's what i'm referring to -- doing all the inserts with one sql statement.

Comment: @JohnBachir Ah. Well let me know if you do figure it out - I could use it as well.

Comment: @Nolan alas, it's not possible via `ActiveRecord` (unless it's been added in rails 4)

Comment: What about PL/SQL procedures? Using it the network latency will reduced to 1, Correct me if i am wrong @Cody Poll

Answer (score 22):

Unfortunately, it's not possible in Rails out of the box.

However, [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) is a great gem for Rails 3.x that adds an `import` method to your model classes, and does exactly what you want as a single SQL insert statement.

Comment: works beautifully with my Rails 4 Postgres 9.3 Ruby 2.1 setup and is infinitely faster than my previous method of calling create on each iteration or Klump's method of calling create once on an array.

Comment: this article was very helpful to me https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/

Answer (score 15):

Rails 6 now supports this out of the box:

https://web.archive.org/web/20191216050322/https://blog.bigbinary.com/2019/04/15/bulk-insert-support-in-rails-6.html

> Bulk inserts can be performed using newly added methods: insert_all,
> insert_all! and upsert_all.

Answer (score 2):

Since Ruby on Rails 6.0 the method `insert_all` is available and saves multiple records into the database with just a single query, good for constant time complexity O(1)

```
VoteRecord.insert_all([
    { :prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "GE", :election => "2011-11-08", :party => row[82], :participate => participated(row[82]) },
    { :prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR", :election => "2011-09-13", :party => row[81], :participate => participated(row[81]) }
    ...
  ])
```

Answer (score -9):

You can wrap your ActiveRecord statements inside an `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction`:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do 
  1000.times { Post.create(options) } 
end
```

See [this post](https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/) for other techniques.

Comment: The OP asked whether they could do better than inserting one at a time. A transaction doesn't prevent that though it helps a bit. [This benchmark](https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/) for instance finds that whilst putting in a transaction will improve by 30% a single `INSERT` was 7000% faster. I'd go with what @nonrectangular said.

Comment: Please don't use this as this will not commit to database until all 1000 records are inserted. This is like postponing the problems.