# Paperclip multiple image upload

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, html, jquery-ui, paperclip

Trying to achieve this without breaking the existing data save structure. I have a form that uploads a *single image* to **asset**. **Edit** Modified the form for 5 image assets. *See below*. . .

The form reads below:

```
<%= form_for @asset, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<div class="span10">
  <%= render 'shared/asset_errors' %>
  <h3>Upload to Procedure Folder</h3>
</div>
<div class="span5">
  <% @procedures = @patient.procedure_folders.all %>
  <%= f.label :procedure_folder_id, "Procedure" %>
  <%= f.select :procedure_folder_id, @procedures.map { |p|
    [Procedure.find(p.procedure_id).procedure, p.id] } %>
  </div>
  <div class="span5">
    <%= f.label :date %>
    <%= f.text_field :date, 'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker'  %>
  </div>
  <div class="span10">
    <%= f.label :notes %>
    <%= f.text_field :notes %>
  </div>
  <div class="span10">
    <% 5.times do |image| %>
    <p><%= f.file_field :asset, name: "asset[asset][#{image}]",
    id: "asset_asset_#{image}" %></p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="span10">
    <%= f.hidden_field :patient_id, value: @patient.id %>
    <%= f.submit "Upload", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

What I would like to achieve -- and have read through some of the methods listed -- is to either static place 5 form fields in this form.. or make it jquery ready with a "add another photo" button.

Class and Controller

Class first:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :asset, :asset_content_type, :asset_file_name, :asset_file_size, :asset_updated_at, :patient_id, :procedure_folder_id, :date, :notes
  belongs_to :procedure_folder
  belongs_to :patient

  has_attached_file :asset, :styles => { :large => "800x600", 
                                                                             :thumb => "150x150" }

  validates :date, presence: true
  validates :patient_id, presence: true
  validates :asset, :attachment_presence => true

  default_scope order: 'assets.date ASC'
end
```

Controller:

```rb
class AssetsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :signed_in_user

    def create
        @asset = Asset.new(params[:asset])
        if @asset.save
            flash[:success] = "Images uploaded successfully!"
            redirect_to patient_path(@asset.patient_id)
        else
            flash[:error] = "There was an error, Date and Image is required!"
            redirect_to patient_path(@asset.patient_id)
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @asset = Asset.find(params[:id])
        set_variables
        if !current_user.admin?
            flash[:error] = "You do not have delete priviledges"
            redirect_to procedure_folder_path(@asset.procedure_folder_id)
        else
            @asset.destroy
            flash[:info] = "Image has been deleted and cannot be recovered"
            redirect_to procedure_folder_path(@asset.procedure_folder_id)
        end
    end

    def set_variables
    end
end
```

What steps can I take to effectively keep the existing structure and avoid adding in a second form. This is running on a small production environment and would like to avoid screwing with existing data... (will test on dev naturally before we use it live).

Any thoughts/tips/solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

**Edit**

Now that the form comes up properly I receive the following error when uploading multiple images.

```
 Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError in AssetsController#create

No handler found for {"0"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f88c517c230 @original_filename="Screen Shot 2013-02-11 at 11.03.46 PM.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"asset[asset][0]\"; filename=\"Screen Shot 2013-02-11 at 11.03.46 PM.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/8k/ctb40yd92w13qyjj3fn0gdnc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20130604-13969-jzz7cl>>, "1"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f88c563bb40 @original_filename="Screen Shot 2013-03-18 at 10.59.47 PM.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"asset[asset][1]\"; filename=\"Screen Shot 2013-03-18 at 10.59.47 PM.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/8k/ctb40yd92w13qyjj3fn0gdnc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20130604-13969-1h5qj85>>, "2"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f88c563da30 @original_filename="Screen Shot 2013-03-18 at 11.01.06 PM.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"asset[asset][2]\"; filename=\"Screen Shot 2013-03-18 at 11.01.06 PM.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/8k/ctb40yd92w13qyjj3fn0gdnc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20130604-13969-1xsd0fk>>}

Rails.root: /Users/sandovalg/Documents/rails_projects/autre_dlz
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/assets_controller.rb:5:in `new'
app/controllers/assets_controller.rb:5:in `create'

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"RjRFHgYu/4fHRl0iksOkivVOR4ikIvavvXxoqSoTMW0=",
 "asset"=>{"procedure_folder_id"=>"1",
 "date"=>"2013-06-04",
 "notes"=>"",
 "asset"=>{"0"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f88c517c230 @original_filename="Screen Shot 2013-02-11 at 11.03.46 PM.png",
 @content_type="image/png",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"asset[asset][0]\"; filename=\"Screen Shot 2013-02-11 at 11.03.46 PM.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n",
 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/8k/ctb40yd92w13qyjj3fn0gdnc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20130604-13969-jzz7cl>>,
 "1"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f88c563bb40 @original_filename="Screen Shot 2013-03-18 at 10.59.47 PM.png",
 @content_type="image/png",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"asset[asset][1]\"; filename=\"Screen Shot 2013-03-18 at 10.59.47 PM.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n",
 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/8k/ctb40yd92w13qyjj3fn0gdnc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20130604-13969-1h5qj85>>,
 "2"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f88c563da30 @original_filename="Screen Shot 2013-03-18 at 11.01.06 PM.png",
 @content_type="image/png",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"asset[asset][2]\"; filename=\"Screen Shot 2013-03-18 at 11.01.06 PM.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n",
 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/8k/ctb40yd92w13qyjj3fn0gdnc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20130604-13969-1xsd0fk>>},
 "patient_id"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Upload"}
```

Comment: If I'm following you correctly, you want to store a list of pictures in a field where you were storing a single picture? With minimal change?

Comment: Yes, correct. Would like to be able . . . utilizing the same form.. to gain the ability to upload multiple photos. As an example **f.file_field :asset** to accept _:asset[1], :asset[2], :asset[x]_. Does that help clarify the request? Thank you kindly for your comment.

Comment: well there is quite a bit to do, model associations for one, so a patient has_many assets? also there will be some small javascript involved but take a look at the following railscasts http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast and  http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip

Comment: Oh, oh, wait. I wasn't getting it at first. One form, uploaded with five assets, results in five assets being added to the database? Not *one* asset with *five* photos, but *five* `Asset`s each with *one* photo.

Comment: Yes, one form to upload 5 asset(s) using the same form.

Comment: Let me make this transparent using the form above upload _**five (5)**_ `Asset`s. To accomplish it simply --hopefully-- by adding _**five (5)**_ `<%= f.file_field :asset %>` . . . however, I am not having any luck with getting this to work.

Comment: Made some changes to the form. Now the problem lies in the error trying to get it to upload.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are saving the records into the same database as your form, it seems that you need to discount using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, which is what I'd normally use with Paperclip

**Saving Multiple Records At Once**

It seems your main problem is saving multiple records at once:

```
No handler found for {"0"=>
```

This shows that Rails is not able to compute the save function, as it's only designed for single params. You'll actually have to save the records with a manual SQL query, like these resources:

- [INSERT multiple records using ruby on rails active record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022178/insert-multiple-records-using-ruby-on-rails-active-record)
- [How to implement bulk insert in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505263/how-to-implement-bulk-insert-in-rails-3)

Essentially, you somehow have to loop through your params array, and save the data in one bulk way. Here is one way you could do it:

As per one of those links, you could use the **[`activerecord-import`](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import)** gem

```
def create
assets = []
    params[:asset].each do |k,v| 
       assets << Asset.new(params[:asset][k])
    end
    Asset.import assets
end
```