# Why i'm getting ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, activerecord, hash

I have an array of objects which i'm sending to the `controller` through `ajax`.

My ajax request is like this:

```
$.ajax({
  data: {
    product: [{'name': 'ahmad', 'price': 'tench', 'quantity': '12'}, {'name': 'gulshan', 'price': 'tench', 'quantity': '12'}]
  },
  url: '',
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function ( data ) {
    console.log(data);
    // this.setState({ comments: data });
  }.bind(this)
});
```

**Controller:**

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
  if @product.save
    render json: @product
  else
    render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

private

def product_params
  params.fetch(:product).permit!
end
```

But if i use `create` method then also i'm getting the same error.

I'm attaching a screenshot of the parameters in the rails log.

[image]

I dont understand why i'm getting this error?

Please help.

Comment: could you post the controller's action code?

Comment: I have added the controller's code. Please check

Comment: you are sending multiple products to your controller, which doesn't know how to handle this. You can iterate over the product_params and save a product one by one (you can put this into a separate class).

Comment: Btw, we may use `require` instead of `fetch`

Comment: Ok but `create` method can take array of hashes. right ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724347/iterate-through-array-of-hashes-in-ruby
But here also i'm getting  the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is that since you're passing an array of `products`, your Rails' strong params are unable to determine the attributes to pass.

Strong params expects:

```
params: {
   product: {
     "name" => "Test"
   }
}
```

This way, when you `require(:product).permit(:name)`, the strong params module will slice up the hash as required. Because your hash looks like the following, it is hitting a problem:

```
params: {
   product: [
     {"name" => "test"},
     {"name" => "test2"}
   ]
}
```

--

Might be worth looking at [nested values](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#nested-parameters):

```
params.permit(:product => [{:name, :price, :quantity}])
```

Answer (score 0):

So i tried many things but failed to do anything with it till this point.

```
product_arr = []
product_params.each_pair { |key, product| product_arr << product }
@products = Product.create(product_arr)
```

`each_pair` returns the response in keys and values.