# How can I create multiple records in Rails using single POST request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, activerecord

I have a rails api which I have generated using scaffolding in rails. 
I have a Product model in this api. To test my api I am creating the products using curl, currently I can create only one product at a time using the curl command

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"product: {"name":"Felix" }}' http://localhost:3000/products.json
```

Now I want to modify my api in a way that it can create multiple products from one post request so that a request something like can be executed and I can create multiple products in one request.

```
 curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{products: {"product": {"name":"Felix" }, {"product": {"name":"Felix" } }' http://localhost:3000/products.json
```

I need help in two things

1) How to modify my create function (which is generated from scaffold) so that it can create accept an array of products(length of array can be variable) and create multiple records for them

2) What hash of data to be passed to curl to test the implemented functionality

Comment: the create method can take an array of hashes and will try to create each object based on the attributes of the hash, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSERT multiple records using ruby on rails active record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022178/insert-multiple-records-using-ruby-on-rails-active-record)

Comment: can you tell me how should I pass array of multiple products in the json hash ?

Comment: probably like `'{"product":[{"name":"Felix1"},{"name":"Felix2"}]}'`

Comment: If I don't change my create action and pass this in my curl command, then I am getting this error **NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for [{"name"=>"Felix1"}, {"name"=>"Felix2"}]:Array)**

Comment: @LovishChoudhary what happened with you mate!
I'm facing the same problem!

Answer (score -1):

In the source of the ActiveRecord#create method, you can see that it loops through the array.  You can do something like this yourself to include strong parameters.

```
def create
  if params[:product].is_a? Array
    params[:product].map { |hash| Product.create(product_params(hash)) }
  else
    # normal action
  end
  # handle redirects and renders
end

private

def product_params(hash_of_params)
  # return results of strong params
end
```